# Intervals of Sets

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $S$ is a set with the property that $|x-y| \geq 1$ for any two
>   different elements $x$ and $y$ of $S$. Show that an interval $(a,a+1)$
>   can contain at most one element of $S$. Does this result change if a
>   half-open or closed interval is used instead of an open interval?

I have no clue where to start with this.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $|x-y|>1$?

Comment: @grand_chat no it should be |x-y|>=1 which is the same as |x-y|>0

Comment: I feel there's a lot of confusion. What are the elements of $S$?

Comment: If $x = .5$ and $y = .6$, $|x-y| > 0$, but $|x-y| \not\geq 1$.  Do you want $S$ to be a set of integers?

Comment: X and y are elements of S

Comment: @D_S I'm not sure. My book doesn't specify, but possibly

Comment: $|x-y|$ being $\geq 1$ is clearly not equivalent to $|x-y| > 0$, as my example shows.  Unless $S$ has some additional property you haven't mentioned, the thing you're trying to prove is impossible.

Comment: Then assume |x-y|>=1

Comment: X and y are elements of S – britgirl5 ... what is $S$???!!! Positive natural numbers? Complex numbers? Real numbers? Integers with exactly 42 different prime factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try drawing a picture.  The elements of $S$ are at least one unit apart.  So naturally there can't be two elements of $S$ within a the space of one unit.

Formally, suppose $x \in (a,a+1)$, with $x \in S$.  If $y$ is another element of $S$ which is also in $(a,a+1)$, we want to show that actually $x = y$.  If this is not the case, then one of these numbers has to be less than the other, say $x < y$.  So we have $$a < x < y < a+1$$ which implies that the difference $y-x$ is less than the difference between $(a+1)$ and $a$ (do you see why?).  But the difference between $(a+1)$ and $a$ is one.  Thus $|y-x| < 1$, contradiction.